# Force sync of existing data to AD

Tags: 2010, active-directory, user-profile-service

I've had UPS set up for a year now with no problems but the business is requesting that some fields (mobile number for example) from the user profile be exported to AD.  I've configured this correctly and updated a mobile number field for a single user, the delta change was picked up and the field updated in AD.

Now I know this works how can I force the sync of all users without them editing the field and relying on the delta being picked up?

thanks

Comment: Have you setup User Profile Synchronization Service ?? PS: Only works with Enterprise SharePoint version

Comment: @Arsalan Yes the service has been setup and working (i.e. it imports users and data from AD) for over a year now.  We are using SharePoint Standard 2010 with Feb CU

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean How can you update the Mobile Phone field for all your users? Or How do you Force SharePoint to perform the export?

Comment: @Matthew I meant how do I force sharepoint to perform the export.  Sorry if it wasn't clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for SharePoint to export the values, I believe they must change. The Delta Export picks up the changes on an incremental. I believe, though I have not tested, that if you do a full sync all values will be exported.

In the User Profile Service Application, Choose Start Synchronization and Select Full Sync. Click OK.